# Where to download Broadcom STA .deb file?

Tags: broadcom, downloads, deb

Situation: I don't have wireless access through Ubuntu due to needing the Broadcom STA driver for my wireless card. I don't currently have access to a physical (cabled) connection that will allow my Ubuntu machine access. (Security reasons, no unidentified machines.)

**Where can I download a .deb file for the Broadcom STA driver?**

I'm not asking how to install through jockey-gtk (the "Additional Drivers" menu option) or through Synaptic.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

**Update:** the answer worked beautifully in an older version of Ubuntu that included Gdebi (an installer for .deb files.) However, in my 11.10 install, the software center churned and churned with no apparent results. Has anyone else tried this in an 11.10+ version, and did software center work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I found it [here](http://andym3.wordpress.com/projects/the-broadcom-wireless-card-guide/)

The site to download from is http://packages.ubuntu.com

> **Installing the Broadcom STA (wl) driver**
>   **Ubuntu:** you’ll need to download the following
>   packages (choose your Ubuntu release, architecture and mirror): dkms,
>   patch,
>   fakeroot
>   and bcmwl-kernel-source.
>   After you’ve downloaded the .deb files, use a USB flashdrive or some
>   other means of file transfer to get them on the computer you want to
>   install to. Then, just double-clicking each file should bring up
>   Ubuntu Software Center and let you install it.
>  Then just navigate
>   to System > Administration > Additional Drivers (or Hardware
>   Drivers for older releases) and activate the Broadcom STA driver.
>   Check out this
>   page for more information about online installation, but please
>   note that the offline installation instructions are pretty much
>   outdated for wl.
>  **Important note:** if this fails,
>   use [Keryx](http://keryxproject.org/download/) (0.92, not
>   1.0) to do an offline upgrade and install the bcmwl-kernel-source package. An up-to-date Keryx tutorial is on my to-do list.
>   **Other distributions:** you can compile the STA driver
>   yourself. 32-bit
>   .tar.gz, 64-bit
>   .tar.gz, readme.
>   The readme explains how to compile the drivers pretty well, so I’m not
>   going to do that here.
>
> [source](http://andym3.wordpress.com/projects/the-broadcom-wireless-card-guide/)

Comment: I'll be sure to update if it worked or not.

Comment: Be sure to link to http://packages.ubuntu.com pages, where you can download these packages.

Comment: You read my mind.